# How to dynamically add route to script src on an html page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an HTML page that has a reference to some scripts like these ones:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="Content/Styles/ThemeForest/assets/js/vendors.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="Content/Styles/ThemeForest/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

The problem is, that when I upload my site to a server, it is no longer working.
I figured that if I instead add the web application name, it will work again. Something like this:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="MySite/Content/Styles/ThemeForest/assets/js/vendors.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="MySite/CContent/Styles/ThemeForest/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Now, the thing is, that I may not know how the web application name would be like once it is uploaded to a server... so, I would like to dynamically add the application name to the src.

I noticed that there is a JavaScript function called window.location.pathname, which can bring me the web application name (if any). I could concatenate this to the rest of the route and it should work.

Now, the catch is, this is all on a regular HTML page.
Is there a way that I can set a custom route to those script tags using basic JavaScript functions? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Could you try using <base href="/"> ?

Comment: Sounds like root-relative paths might work, something like `/Content/Styles/ThemeForest/assets/js/vendors.js`. Is there any reason you couldn't simply use root-relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [$script](https://github.com/ded/script.js/), just add that lines of code in your app.run or any other place, and call it with an array of the routes of the js files that you want to load. You said that you could get the web application name, so just pass the name of the app concatenated with the path of the script:

```
var dependenciesLoadingFactory = function(deps) {
    return ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $script(deps, function() {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() { deferred.resolve(); });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you link to a source document starting with a directory or the filename itself (like you did in your question), the lookup will look for it starting in the same folder that your current file (this would be the html file that holds your script tags) is in.
You could also link to files in parent directories relative to your current location, like this:

```
../file.js
```

You can alternatively link to a path starting with a slash:

```
/dir/to/your/file.js
```

This will start looking in the root directory of your page, meaning the directory your domain or subdomain points to. You can't successfully link to files that are above your root directory.

Finally, if your files are on another server, make sure you include the full path including the http:// snippet:

```
http://example.website.com/dir/file.js
```

Under normal circumstances, there should really be no reason to deviate from these methods, but if you absolutely have to dynamically set a directory, I suggest you use php because it's server-side and therefore faster for the user, and available if they have javascript disabled (which is important if you link to other files such as style sheets in this way):

```
<?php $directory = '/dir/'; ?>
<script src="<?php print $directory; ?>file.js"></script>
```

Of course for this to work, your server has to have php running.

Comment: I'd like feedback on why this post has been downvoted. The author of the question asked for other-than-javascript ideas in their original post.